# need help with ufw

Tags: ssh, ufw

I am setting up ufw using ansible on a remote ubuntu server.
I am initially setting up ufw with `ufw enable policy allow` to enable ssh access.
After that I'm doing `ufw allow from x.x.x.x to any port 22` to allow ssh from a specific port

After that I fire in the command `ufw deny ssh` to deny ssh from all other places except the above IP.

I then restart ufw services

But, this does not prevent ssh at all. I'm able to access the server from every place via ssh.

How can I block all ports after settings ufw policy to allow.

Comment: "Rule  ordering  is important and the first match wins. Therefore when adding rules, add the more specific rules first with more general rules later." - `man ufw`

Comment: @steeldriver: yes i did that. ssh from a specific IP was added first. Then the deny rule was added.

Comment: What is `ufw enable policy allow` though? I don't see mention of that syntax in the manpage. If you set the default incoming policy to allow first, that would take precedence.

Comment: sorry, that option is specific to ansible.  it enables incoming by default. i have to do that because ufw immediately blocks ssh when enabled.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ansible, but with regular ufw the way around that is to specify all the the rules required to allow your essential services *before* enabling ufw

Comment: That's interesting, because when I use the commands for ufw before enabling, I get message ufw inactive

Comment: Is systemctl status ufw; systemctl unmask ufw; systemctl enable ufw; systemctl stop iptables; systemctl mask iptables; systemctl stop iptablesd; systemctl mask iptablesd; systemctl start ufw; systemctl status ufw

Answer (score 0):

I would configure ufw this way:

first, make sure ufw is **inactive** so you do not cut off yourself

```
sudo ufw status # should say inactive if not, turn it off
```

than configure (note that order is critical):

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming    # applied at the end of the last rule
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw allow from x.x.x.x to any 22
```

these rules should do it as the only ssh from your specified IP is allowed.

then turn on the firewall by:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: You may also note that the order of the commands is important.

Comment: Ufw allow ipv4 needs to be at the top then use  ufw deny all ssh , it reads line one and works it's way down, if it reads deny before allow it will deny everything, but if you ask it to allow an IP before it denies everything then one will be allowed through